# Cannot read image with See3CAM with Python 3 and open CV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, camera

I am trying to read an image from a camera from e-Con Systems using Python 3.4 and OpenCV. The camera uses DirectShow drivers and I can connect to the camera (isOpened returns true and the status LED on the camera is active) but when I try to read or grab a frame it does not work.

```
import cv2
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(cv2.CAP_DSHOW + device)
cam.isOpened()  # returns true, camera LED on
flag, frame = cam.read() # flag=false, frame=None
```

I have also tried capturing multiple frames as others have stated, but still no luck!

Comment: may I know which camera you are using & the output format of the camera?

Comment: 1.3MP camera dev board. 
www.e-consystems.com/1MP-USB3-Near-IR-Camera.asp

Comment: May I know what Opencv version you are using & Windows or Linux?

Comment: Have you solved your problem? Feel free to ask any questions if you have any!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you can see from the camera specification, the Camera Output format is Y16 i.e. 16-Bit Monochrome format. By default opencv / Direct show does not support this format!

**Building OpenCV for See3CAM Custom Format**

Here is the step by step procedure to build OpenCV with custom Frame format support.

1. Download [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/downloads.html)
2. Download modified [cap_dshow.cpp](http://www.e-consystems.com/downloads/e-con_Modified_OpenCV.zip).

Note: This source code is modified for supporting Y16 & BY8 formats only.

3. Select required configuration- For building x86 or x64 Bit library and Build OpenCV [official guide](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html).
4. Replace the existing cap_dshow.cpp

I.  For OpenCV 2.x.x path: OpenCV/sources/modules/highgui/src

II. For OpenCV 3.x.x path: OpenCV/sources/modules/videoio/src

5. Open OpenCV.sln solution file & build the OpenCV library.

Here is a sample c++ application for streaming a camera with 16-Bit image format. I hope it is very simple to port this to python! Hope this helps!

```
#include "CTimer.h"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int, char** argv )
{
    const int iWidth=1280;
    const int iHeight=720;

    CTimer t_FPS;
    t_FPS.Init();

    VideoCapture Capture(0);

    if(!Capture.isOpened())
    {
        cout<< "Cannot Open Camera!";
        return 0;
    }
    Capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,iWidth);
    Capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,iHeight);

    namedWindow("Camera NIR Frame",WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    Mat mCamFrame_10,mCamFrame_8;

    char key;
    for(;;)
    {

        Capture >> mCamFrame_10; // get a new frame from camera

        if(mCamFrame_10.empty()||mCamFrame_10.rows==0||mCamFrame_10.cols==0)
        {
            cout<< "Invalid Frame Frame Empty"<<"\n";
            break;
        }

        //Convert to 8 Bit: Scale the 10 Bit (1024) Pixels into 8 Bit(256) (256/1024)= 0.25
        convertScaleAbs(mCamFrame_10,mCamFrame_8,0.25);

        imshow("Camera NIR Frame", mCamFrame_8);

        t_FPS.Update();
        cout<<"Frame Rate: "<<t_FPS.GetFPS()<<"\n";
        key = cv::waitKey(1);
        if(key == 27)
        {
            //Esc Key is pressed & Exit the Application
            break;
        }
    }
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
    // the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor
}
```

Comment: solution file? I am using python. Do I need to install Visual Studio to compile this?

Comment: How will you build opencv from source? Just follow official guide for building opencv

Comment: We managed to build it and it seems to work and capture. The image it returns is just noise however and the numpy array doesn't appear complete. we are trying to see why

Comment: when i use cap.read(), or grab() then retrieve(), the status LED on the device does not blink like the eCAM software. They both return a numpy array which appear incorrect and this image is wrong.
Also I cannot set() variables (like image width/height etc)
>>> for i in range(0, 22):
...   cap.get(i)
...
-1.0
-1.0
-1.0
640.0
480.0
0.0
540422489.0
-1.0
-1.0
-1.0
1.0
59267632.0
59267632.0
59267632.0
59267632.0
-4.0
-1.0
59267632.0
-1.0
59267632.0
59267632.0
-1.0

Comment: source is my frame, what is mSource_8? how is this defined?
convertscaleabs(mSource_16,mSource_8,255.0/4096);

Comment: it's a numpy array. i have that. The issue isn't the format at the moment sorry, the issue is that the status light DOES NOT turn on when there is a capture. The led does flash when using the eCAM software. Also I cannot change width/height etc.

Comment: It would be nice to show us your code & output, So that I can help further!

Comment: yes i have a ticket with econ but it is very slow to respond. the code is the standard python video capture code. the opencv build is the standard opencv build with the modified c files from econ

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102343/discussion-between-balaji-r-and-jme).

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I just got a SeeCam40 and I thought I would be able to plug this into python pretty easily. There doesn't seem to be any way to do that without building OpenCV with their modified CPP file and then using their C code to build an app. I'm much more comfortable in python and have working code that does what I want with the input images. @jme

Answer (score 1):

Eons ago I've written a patch for OpenCV that provides support for the Y16 codec, so you no longer have to go through all this pain of doing a custom-compile of OpenCV. I have emailed E-con support about this at the time, but (as of time of this post) I see there's been no attempt on their part to adjust how they do things.

Brandon Hurr / @bhive01 has written some python code using this for the See3CAM_CU40, you can check it out [over here](https://gist.github.com/bhive01/). It's very much how you would use OpenCV's `VideoCapture` interface, just using 'Y','1','6','' for the FOURCC setting, and setting CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, to false.

Cheers!